# Running a child process as the parent process

Tags: c, windows, process, exec

Is it possible to run a child process as a parent process?

My directory structure looks like this:

- app/program.exe

  - app/bin/internal.exe
  - app/bin/something.dll

The `program.exe` just executes the `internal.exe` with some arguments.

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <process.h> 

int main(void) {
    _execl(".\\bin\\internal.exe",
        "internal.exe", "some args", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The arguments are important; without them `internal.exe` won't do anything.

This mostly works alright, but doesn't integrate well with the taskbar. The program shows up in the taskbar as `internal.exe`, and pinning it to the taskbar isn't useful, because clicking on the pinned shortcut will execute `internal.exe` without the arguments, and it will close immediately.

I'd like it to show up as `program.exe` on the taskbar, so that pinning it to the taskbar pins the working "launcher" instead of the internal part.

Is this possible?

Comment: execl will replace 'program.exe' with 'internal.exe'. In other words 'program.exe' is ciezed to exist.

Comment: You could try changing the second `_execl()` argument from `"internal.exe"` to `"program.exe"`.  That won't change what program is actually run, but it might change what gets displayed on the taskbar.

Comment: Right, unfortunately the `spawn` family of functions don't fare any better (some spawn modes keep parent around, but child still shows up in taskbar). I'm hoping that there's some winapi function I don't know about that'll take care of this. @JohnBollinger that second arg doesn't seem to have any effect at all, although I think what actually shows up there gets cached in the registry. But it's more important that the "launcher" gets pinned and runs "internal" with the args, really.

Comment: what sense in *program.exe* ? if only exec *internal.exe* with some args - this no sense. simply if *internal.exe* started with no args - use this default args

Comment: @RbMm I'm not the author of "internal.exe" and don't want to create an altered-source version in order to hard-code some arguments, that would have to be a last resort. There are also organizational reasons (for example I've built two versions of "internal.exe," one runs with a console for debugging and one doesn't; both offload everything to the DLLs. I want to keep the root directory clean of multiple EXEs and DLLs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the child to become the parent in terms of actual processes. The taskbar works at a higher level and gives you more control.

[MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/appids):

> The following items describe common scenarios that **require an explicit AppUserModelID**. They also point out cases where multiple explicit AppUserModelIDs should be used.
>
> ...
>
> Cooperative or chained processes that to the user are part of the same application should have the same AppUserModelID applied to each process. Examples include games with a launcher process (chained) and Microsoft Windows Media Player, which has a first-run/setup experience running in one process and the main application running in another process (cooperative).

If you are not the author of the child application things become complicated.

If it is Java or some other type of framework it should have the `IsHostApp` value set. If not, you can try playing with [`UseExecutableForTaskbarGroupIcon` and `TaskbarGroupIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/app-registration) but these will not change the AppUserModelID. Setting `NoStartPage` will prevent the user from pinning the child application.

If you know how to find the window of the child application you can call [`SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetpropertystoreforwindow) in the parent and set the id to the same [id as your parent process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-setcurrentprocessexplicitappusermodelid) and/or set the `System.AppUserModel.Relaunch*` properties.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I'm creating windows in the subprocess and setting the "Relaunch" properties on them there should be good enough, the parent can probably be left untouched (the subprocess is a JIT compiler with a good FFI).